# Jenkins not able to pull from github using SSH

Tags: spring-boot, github, jenkins

This is the error that i am getting when building the freestyle project.

```
Started by user Amith Sai 
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on JenkinsAgent (gradle docker) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SSH POC PROJECT
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential SSHGITHUB
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:MRROBOT-124/POC-PROJECT.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SSH POC PROJECT # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:MRROBOT-124/POC-PROJECT.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.39.2'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials GITHUB SSH KEYS
Verifying host key using known hosts file, will automatically accept unseen keys
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:MRROBOT-124/POC-PROJECT.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:MRROBOT-124/POC-PROJECT.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2732)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:623)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:850)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:158)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:151)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JenkinsAgent
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:143)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor805.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:129)
        at jdk.proxy66/jdk.proxy66.$Proxy161.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1226)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1309)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1240)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:649)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:521)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have the following project configuration setup in Jenkins.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTIi.png)
I did create a ssh key by using the following commands:

```
sudo su jenkins
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail.com"
```

I did not leave the password empty. I did provide a password when generating the SSH key.
I pasted the public key in github by going to settings -> SSH and GPG keys
and in jenkins i went to manage jenkins -> manage credentials and added the private key

Whenever i try to build the project its giving me the above mentioned error. Jenkins is not able to connect with github and pull the project.

I am not sure why its behaving this way. My  Git Host Key Verification Configuration  is set to Accept first connection. I even tried switching it to No Verification and it still didn't work.

If i used username and password instead of SSH keys everything seems to be working. Does someone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

> If I used username and password instead of SSH keys everything seems to be working. Does someone have any idea on how to resolve this?

> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
> Blockquote

That seems to indicate that, like at my company, any SSH egress is blocked.
Meaning, you can use HTTPS URLs to GitHub, but not SSH ones.

If that is the case, no need to define and register SSH keys, your corporate policy might not allow SSH URLs anyway.

Comment: If egress is blocked, OP could try [Corkscrew](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew), a tool for tunneling SSH through HTTP proxies.

Comment: @IanW At first, I never managed to make it work on a corporate Windows PC. Then I never dare to make it work in said corporate environment. Side-stepping security, however technically feasible it might be, it not well appreciated by an IT Sec department ;)

Comment: I am just trying to set it up on my personal system. I do not know why ssh would be blocked. i tried connecting to github using ssh and it seems to be working fine.